# Is a CUDA-programmed GPU suitable for implementation of OpenCV adaptive threshold?

Tags: opencv, cuda

On my system, for a 5 MP image with a large window size (75px) it takes a whopping **140 ms (roughly 20 times as much as linear operations)** to complete and I am looking to optimize it. I have noticed that the OpenCV gpu module does not implement a gpu version of the `adaptiveThreshold` so I have been thinking of implementing that algorithm for the GPU myself.

Can I hope for any speedup if I implement an adaptive threshold algorithm in CUDA, based on a large window size (50px+) and a large image (5 MP+), ignoring the overhead for loading memory into the GPU?

`adaptiveThreshold` documentation on opencv.org:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation by CUDA should give you a satisfied performance gain.

Since your window size is large, this operation should be compute-bounded. The theoretical peak performance of a 5 MP image with 75px window on a [Tesla K20X GPU](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-servers.html) should be about

```
5e6 * 75 * 75 / 3.95 Tflops = 7ms
```

Here's a white paper about image convolution. It shows how to implement a high performance box filer with CUDA.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/3_Imaging/convolutionSeparable/doc/convolutionSeparable.pdf

Nvidia cuNPP library also provides a function `nppiFilterBox()`, which can be used to implement `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C` directly.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#box-filter-with-npp

For `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C`, the function `nppiFilter()` with a proper mask could be used.

NPP doc pp.1009 http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/NPP_Library.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Building on Eric's answer:

The Npp CUDA library does not implement adaptiveThreshold but it seems beneficial to getting an adaptive threshold in a VERY straightforward way (just tested it and anecdotally works):

1. Run a box filter on `src` (i.e. compute mean window value for every pixel),
   store in an intermediate image `tmp`.
2. Subtract a number K from each pixel in `tmp`
3. Run a compare function between `src` and
   `tmp` into `dst`. The end.

The code may look like this (here K=0, 2nd step omitted):

```
nppiFilterBox_8u_C1R(oDeviceSrc.data(), oDeviceSrc.pitch(),
                                  oDeviceIntermediate.data(), oDeviceDst.pitch(),
                                  oSizeROI, oAdapThreshWindowSize,oAnchor);
nppiCompare_8u_C1R(oDeviceSrc.data(),oDeviceSrc.pitch(),
                   oDeviceDst.data(),oDeviceDst.pitch(),
                   oDeviceResult.data(),oDeviceResult.pitch(),
                   oSizeROI,NPP_CMP_LESS);
```

Also, wikipedia [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur) that applying a box filter 3 times in a row approximates a Gaussian filter to 97% accuracy.

Comment: Do you have any full source code you can link?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this algorithm can be optimized on the GPU. I would expect to see an excellent speedup.

For `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C`, you could use a standard parallel reduction to calculate the arithmetic mean. For `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C`, you might use a kernel that performs per-pixel gaussian attenuation combined with a standard parallel reduction for the sum.